# Closed form of a recurrence function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm looking to search for the closed form function of the recurrence

$A(n) = A(n-1)/2 + 1/A(n-1)$

Where  $A(0) = 2$

The reurrence isn't divide and conquer neither homogeneous so I don't have any idea where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: let $B(n) = \frac{A(n)-\sqrt{2}}{A(n)+\sqrt{2}}$, express $B(n+1)$ in terms of $B(n)$.

Comment: Are there any basis for that substitution? Edit: Any name for the technique that i can further my research? Thanks

Comment: $\pm \sqrt{2}$ are two fixed points for the map $x \mapsto \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{x}$. If $A(n)$ converge, it will converge to one of these two values. if one work out the expression of $A(n+1) \pm \sqrt{2}$ in terms of $A(n) \pm \sqrt{2}$, one find this particular combination has very simple dependence.